# Correct path for #import of iPhone Frameworks (ALAssetsLibrary.h)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios

This may be the easiest points out there but it is stumping for some reason.  I am trying to include the AssetsLibrary Framework and having issues with getting the compiler to see the actual include file for ALAssetsLibrary when using relative paths.

I am currently using:

```
#import </Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/AssetsLibrary.framework/Headers/ALAssetsLibrary.h>
```

And this works but is oh so bad in that it calls out the device and specific OS build.  I have added the framework and everything links and runs. I just really do not like using the above absolute path and cannot get any relative paths to work.  I have tried many combinations of using quotes ("") and braces (<>).  Various relative paths to just System, Library, System/Library...

XCode specifics:
XCode 3.2.5

Component versions
Xcode IDE: 1760.0
Xcode Core: 1763.0
ToolSupport: 1758.0

Answer (score 56):

Found it.  Don't know why I did not think of this earlier...

```
#import <AssetsLibrary/AssetsLibrary.h>
```

Simple.

Answer (score 4):

In **Swift**:

Please first of all add the AssetsLibrary framework to your Xcode project: click on the name of your project in the project navigator < Then click on the name of your project under TARGETS < Then click on Build Phases < Then click on Link Binary With Libraries < Then click on the "+ button" and add the **AssetsLibrary.framework**

Finally add this import below at the top of your swift class:

```
import AssetsLibrary
```